# Симметрическая разность

Tags: javascript

[Симметрическая разность wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)
Нужно найти симметрическую разность массивов.
Написал функцию сравнения двух массивов, в которой объединяю массивы в один и в цикле ищу повторяющиеся значения. При нахождении удаляю.

```js
function sym() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var result = compareTwoArray(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
  
  if (arguments.length > 2) {
    
    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      // console.log('result = ' + result);
      result = compareTwoArray(result, arguments[i]);
    }
    
  }
  
  return result;
}

function compareTwoArray() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var result = [];
  
  var newArr = args.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(curr);
  })
  
  for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    
    var count = 0;
    
    for (var j = i+1; j < newArr.length; j++) {

      if (newArr[i] === newArr[j]) {
        count += 1;
        newArr.splice(j, 1);
        j -= 1;
      }
      
    }

    if (count === 0) {
      result.push(newArr[i]);
    }
    
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 5]));
// [2, 5]
console.log(sym([1, 1, 3], [4, 6]));
// [1, 3, 4, 6]
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]));
// [1, 3]
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]));
// [1, 4, 5]
console.log(sym([1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]));
// [1, 4, 5]
```

Не знаю, как обрабатывать повторяющиеся значения.
В одном случае его нужно удалить.

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 5]
[2, 5] - должен получиться
[2, 5] - получается с моим кодом
```

В другом оставить.

```
[1, 1, 3]
[4, 6]
[1, 3, 4, 6] - должен получиться
[3, 4, 6] - получается с моим кодом
```

В другом и оставить(1) и удалить(2).

```
[1, 1, 2, 5]
[2, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 3] - должен получиться
[3] - получается с моим кодом
```

Comment: а как это должно работать для трех и более массивов? например, какой ответ ожидается при: `console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]));`

Comment: @Grundy в тексте вопроса есть ведь ответы. Мне симметричная разность напоминает XOR в алгебре логики.

Comment: Ответ [1, 4, 5]. Работает: берем первые два массива, удаляем пересекающиеся числа `[1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]` => `[1, 3]`. Получаем новый массив его сравниваем со следующим массивом `[1, 3], [3, 4, 5, 5]` => `[1, 4, 5]`. У меня в коде две функции `compareTwoArray()` для сравнения и `sym()` для возврата ответа, в случае массивов > 2 вызывается в цикле `compareTwoArray()`, где `result` возврат от предыдущего значения, а `arguments[i]` следующий массив.

Comment: @stackanon, а почему `[1,4,5]` а не `[1,1,4,5,5]`?

Comment: @Grundy повторяющиеся элементы в одном массиве нужно свести к одному элементу

Comment: @Grundy Можно я опять вмешаюсь? :) Я бы даже спросил почему не [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5], но подумал что массивы не очень прямо соответствуют множествам поэтому можно дофантазировать, что элемент 2 пересекается со всеми аналогичными, а в симметричной разности должны быть уникальные элементы

Comment: Все-таки, мне не совсем понятно, почему для трех массивов, в которых есть _5_, она остается в конечном результате?

Comment: @Grundy Ее не становится после в результате первой операции, поскольку она есть в первых двух массивах. Я другого варианта вычисления этой функции для трех элементов кроме как `sym(a, b, c) == sym(sym(a, b), c)` (ну или наоборот - операция ассоциативна) придумать не могу

Comment: Потому что сравниваются по порядку, а не все сразу. Не могу подробней объяснить, сам не до конца понимаю.

Comment: Вы лучше скажите для чего это понадобилось? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @stackanon, Ну да, в таком случае вроде подходят решения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение для двух массивов. Хотя 3 и больше массивов можно обрабатывать ступенчато: сначала два первых, потом результат первой обработки и 3 массив и так далее.

```js
function sum(arr1, arr2) {
  var tmp = arr1.concat(arr2), 
      result = [],
      value, sum;
  for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    var value = tmp[i];
    if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
      sum = 0;
      if (arr1.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        sum++;
      }
      if (arr2.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        sum++;
      }
      if (sum == 1) {
        result.push(value);
      }  
    }  
  } 
  return result;
}

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 5]));
// [2, 5]
console.log(sum([1, 1, 3], [4, 6]));
// [1, 3, 4, 6]
console.log(sum([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]));
// [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 7):

В яваскрипте есть [класс Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), который в данном случае можно использовать в виде множества, в итоге запись получится почти по формуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В примере ниже использовался [spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), и [rest-параметры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)

```js
function sym(...arrs) {
  return arrs.reduce((acc, arr, i) => {
    var accSet = new Set(acc), // множество из элементов первого массива
      arrSet = new Set(arr); // множество из элементов второго массива
    return [...accSet].filter(a => !arrSet.has(a)) // элементы первого множества без элементо второго
      .concat( // объединение
        [...arrSet].filter(a => !accSet.has(a)) // элементы второго множества без элементов первого
      );
  }, []);
}

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 5]));
// [2, 5]
console.log(sym([1, 1, 3], [4, 6]));
// [1, 3, 4, 6]
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]));
// [1, 3]
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]));
// [1, 4, 5]
console.log(sym([1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]));
// [1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Шикарно, как всегда :) Только если это в браузере, то он не должен быть не очень новым (а если совсем старый, то и мое решение не пройдет)

Comment: @tutankhamun, не совсем понял последнее предложение :-)

Comment: Ну вся эта синтаксическая красота работает не во всех браузерах (а ресты, как я посмотрел, вообще только в Firefox)

Comment: @tutankhamun, в хроме отлично работает, даже в EDGE работает. А вот в IE, даже последнем, действительно не работает

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант еще можно сделать так:

```js
function sym() {
  var diff = [];
  // Допускаем, что симметричная разность пустого массива - пустой массив,
  // а симметричная разность одного массива - разность пустого массива
  // и этого массива равна самому этому массиву.
  // Также симметрическая разность равна объединению минус пересечение,
  // поэтому...
  [].forEach.call(arguments, function(arg) {
    var sum = diff.concat(arg);
    // ...объединяем массивы...
    diff = sum.filter(function(item) {
      // ...оставляем только те элементы, которые не найдены хотя бы
      // в одном из массивов...
      return (-1 === arg.indexOf(item) || -1 === diff.indexOf(item));
    });
  });
  // ...возвращаем уникальные элементы
  // (иначе sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]) будет [1, 1, 3])
  return diff.filter(function(item, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(item) === index;
  });
}

console.log(sym());
console.log(sym([1, 2, 3]));

console.log(sym([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 5]));
console.log(sym([1, 1, 3], [4, 6]));
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]));
console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]));
console.log(sym([1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Для `console.log(sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]));` вернуло `[
  1,
  4,
  5
]` И для последнего примера аналогично.

Comment: @Visman Ну так вроде автор вопроса этого и добивался

Comment: @Visman и, кстати, ваш вариант дает такой же результат если выполнить `console.log(sum(sum([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]), [3, 4, 5, 5]));`

Comment: У меня на два массива функция рассчитана, Вы как ее проверили с 3мя массивами? Хм, я кажется запутался :)

Comment: @Visman как вы и указали "результат первой обработки и 3 массив" то есть `sum(sum([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]), [3, 4, 5, 5])` :)

Comment: Я считал, что должно вернуть `[1,4]` и если это так, то мою функцию с 3 и больше массивами использовать нельзя.

Comment: @Visman Вашу функцию и не получиться использовать с 3 и большими массивами т.к. у нее заданы 2 аргумента. Она хорошо подходит для сравнения двух массивов. Что мне и надо было, функция сравнения двух массивов compareTwoArray() и функция вызова sym().

Answer (score 1):

Основывая на описании:

> Симметрическая разность **двух** множеств

Вот пример для двух множеств (докрутить большее количество множеств, думаю, догадаетесь как):

```js
function getDiff(a, b){
  let result  = [],
      pointer = -1;
  
  if(!Array.isArray(a) || !Array.isArray(b))
    throw new Error(`Both arguments must be arrays!`);
  
  a.forEach(e => {
    if((pointer = b.indexOf(e)) !== -1)
      b.splice(pointer, 1);
    else if(result.indexOf(e) === -1)
      result.push(e);
  });
  b.forEach(e => {
    if((pointer = a.indexOf(e)) !== -1)
      a.splice(pointer, 1);
    else if(result.indexOf(e) === -1)
      result.push(e);
  });
  
  return result;
}

// Пример с вики
console.info(getDiff([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));

// Ваши примеры
console.info(getDiff([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 5]));
console.info(getDiff([1, 1, 3], [4, 6]));
console.info(getDiff([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]));
```