# Получить разницу элементов между массивами

Tags: javascript, массивы

Скажем есть два массива:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5];
b = [1,3];
```

нужно получить новый массив С из массива А в котором **исключены** элементы которые есть массиве B, вот так:

```
с = [2,4,5];
```

Вопрос: существует ли способ при котором нет необходимости обрабатывать элементы отдельно, а можно обрабатывать сразу массивы?

Comment: нет, такого способа нет

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Comment: @OlegGranRCM, а какое отношение ruby имеет к javascript?

Comment: @OlegGranRCM под вопросом есть метки, мы сейчас о javascript разговариваем

Comment: c jquery это делается в одну строку `$(a).not(b).get();`  На чистом js больше строк.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо подойдет

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: возможный дубликат: [Симметрическая разность](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572993/186999)

Comment: @perfect но это не точно)

Comment: @Grundy много кода. на самом деле хотелось бы чтото типа: `c = a - b;`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, было б точно, сразу бы закрыл :-)

Comment: @perfect, как я сказал выше - так нельзя. Максимум можно добавить в Array.prototype функцию типа `subtract` и весь код поместить туда. Кода на самом деле не так уж и много: `var hb=new Set(b); result=a.filter(el=>!hb.has(el))`

Comment: @Grundy ну и метод бы подошел типа `c = a.substract(b);`

Comment: @Grundy ну оно работает, если в массиве дубликатов нет))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не совсем понял

Comment: @Grundy забей) в общем, лучше на чистом js от греха подальше)

Comment: `@Grundy много кода. на самом деле хотелось бы чтото типа: c = a - b;` - так можно в helper, в общие функции добавить функцию и использовать её...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выбрать значения одного массива в другой по условию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644703/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: @Other не совсем дубликат - там топикастер уже знает как получить разницу между массивами, и ищет ошибку в конкретной реализации. А тут - просит подсказать решение целиком. Т.е. к этому вопросу не применим ответ "Проблема у вас в том, что когда числа в фильтре нету, то indexOf выводит "-1"", который дан том топике :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну раз 1,3 то != заменить на ==

```
c = a.filter(el => -1 == b.indexOf(el));
```

Comment: Вы можете изменять свой ответ, нажав кнопку [edit], нет нужды постить еще один ответ

Comment: @Zugr спасибо это хорошее решение

Answer (score 0):

`c = a.filter(el => -1 != b.indexOf(el));`

Comment: не работает в С = 1,3