# Выбрать значения одного массива в другой по условию

Tags: javascript

Есть два простых массива: источник (sourceArr) и фильтр (filterArr). Надо из источника забрать только те значение, которые есть в фильтре. Вот код:

```
var sourceArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var filterArr = [2, 3, 8];
var newArr = sourceArr.filter(function(item) {
   return filterArr.indexOf(item);
});
alert( newArr ); // выводит [1,3,4,5,6], а надо бы [2,3]
```

Никак не могу понять в чем дело, хотя код простейший.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема у вас в том, что когда числа в фильтре нету, то indexOf выводит "-1", а это `true`. Что бы оно выводило правильно, нужно добавить перед функцией `~`, которая "-1" будет преобразовывать в "0"

```js
var sourceArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var filterArr = [2, 3, 8];
var newArr = sourceArr.filter(function(item) {
   return ~filterArr.indexOf(item);
});
alert( newArr );
```

Answer (score 1):

Исправьте функцию фильтрации следующим образом:

```
var newArr = sourceArr.filter(function(item) {
   return filterArr.indexOf(item) >= 0;
});
```

и всё должно заработать. Дело в том, что функция `indexOf` возвращает (что логично) индекс найденного элемента, или, если элемент не найден, -1. Однако ваше условие отфильтровывает только нулевой элемент (в результирующий массив попадают все элементы, indexOf для которых не равен 0)

Comment: Лучше [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: @Other чем же он лучше? filter поддерживается всеми более-менее вменяемыми браузерами (даже IE 9  о нём знает) и более гибок в силу возможности задать любое условие для  фильтра. Тогда как includes вообще отсутствует в IE, а Chrome и FF стали поддерживать его недавно (47 и 43 версии)

Comment: Писать - так уж правильно. А транспайлингом пусть Babel занимается.